# How to source /etc/profile and save it in docker?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Docker:`Docker version 1.0.1, build 990021a`

image:`ubuntu:14.04.2` and named vl

I run a ubuntu image and write `:/usr/share/java/mysql.jar` in /etc/profile than source it.

And I commit the container and run it again,but I still can't echo the $CLASSPATH.

The result was blank.How to solve it? Thank you.

Here was my process

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx:~$ sudo docker run -it vl bash
root@04cfd1909a89:/# echo $CLASSPATH
                                                 <<--nothing
root@04cfd1909a89:/# source /etc/profile
root@04cfd1909a89:/# echo $CLASSPATH
:/usr/share/java/mysql.jar
root@04cfd1909a89:/# exit
exit
ubuntu@ip-xxx:~$ sudo docker commit -m="source /etc/profile" -a="changec" 04cfd1909a89 vl
bbb5599e6634ebe694d18fba46f355445f1aa8880b21c22e2d528c022ebf4f84
ubuntu@ip-10-184-10-187:~$ sudo docker run -it vl bash
root@519347159fa5:/# echo $CLASSPATH
                                                 <<--nothing again! why?
root@519347159fa5:/# exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that committing a container only saves the state of the *filesystem*, whereas environment variables are a property of each individual *process*. Your `bash` process dies when you exit the container, and its environment variables go with it. Use this in the `Dockerfile` instead:

```
ENV CLASSPATH :/usr/share/java/mysql.jar
```

Comment: Thank you very much.You do me a big favor

Comment: @changec: Glad it helped! I recommend The Docker Book by James Turnbull; it helped me get quickly up to speed on Docker.